# Adding an object to the lookup

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

I want to create an object in a module and then have it available to other modules via the lookup. I know how to retrieve object from the lookup but I don't know how to put objets in it.

Can anyone tell me the procedure?

Let me be more specific about what I really want to do :

I already know how to select (through the use of a "Favorite" module) and edit (in "Multiviews") a file in a Netbeans platform application. But rather than selecting the file to edit in an Explorer object, I would like to be able to select it through a "File/Open" menu item. This menu item would call an open file dialog and the user selected file would be added to the lookup for use by the views. Is it possible and, if yes, how?

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Comment: That's very clear!!! Can you at least put in the code to look up the object so that we can back track?

Comment: @BharatSinha judging by the tags, I'm guessing he means [this](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-util-lookup/org/openide/util/Lookup.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your own `AbstractLookup` with `InstanceContent`, you can merely do...

```
final InstanceContent content = ...;
content.add(instance);
final Lookup lookup = new AbstractLookup(content);
```

Generally, when using `AbstractLookup`, I **think** you can implement your own `AbstractLookup.Pair` for adding *after* creation time.

```
final AbstractLookup lookup = ...;
lookup.addPair(new AbstractLookup.Pair<MyObject>() {

  final MyObject inst = ...;

  protected boolean creatorOf(final Object inst) {
    return this.inst == inst;
  }

  protected boolean instanceOf(final Class<?> cls) {
    return cls == MyObject.class;
  }

});
```